# Palabra o expresión que se refiera a hacer algo en oposición a una costumbre

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

> Existe alguna palabra o expresión breve es español que se refiera al acto de hacer algo que no es habitual o costumbre?

Si tomásemos la palabra "contracostumbre" como opción válida, ejemplos de su uso serían:

1) A contracostumbre se levantó aquel día a las nueve de la mañana.

2) Decidió a contracostumbre que no quería café.

Comment: A mi me suena más natural "en contra de su costumbre"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí hay otras opciones que se usan habitualmente:

La primera es algo que no es habitual:

> 1. [Inhabitual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LbPdD8c)
>
> Que no es habitual.

La segunda es algo que no se acostumbra:

> 2. [Desacostumbrado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CLfIx6H%7CCLgrSYM)
>
> Fuera del uso y orden común.

La tercera es un sinómimo de la anterior:

> 3. [Inusitado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M1Dt72l)
>
> No usado, desacostumbrado.

La cuarta es otro sinónimo de la segunda:

> 4. [Insólito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Lll9Gzg)
>
> Raro, extraño, desacostumbrado.

La quinta, igual:

> 5. [Desusado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DWqpI82%7CDWr3EEv)
>
> Desacostumbrado, poco o nada habitual. *Lleva ropa de una calidad desusada en él.*

Y finalmente, una palabra que expresa lo mismo pero no aparece definida explícitamente como un sinónimo de la segunda opción:

> 6. [Extraordinario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HP5RXLV)
>
> Fuera del orden o regla natural o común.

Los ejemplos quedarían de la siguiente manera:

> 1) **Inhabitualmente**, se levantó aquel día a las nueve de la mañana.
>
> 2) Decidió **inusitadamente** que no quería café.

Y con otras opciones:

> 1) **Desacostumbradamente**, se levantó aquel día a las nueve de la mañana.
>
> 2) Decidió, **de manera insólita**, que no quería café.

También se utilizan [inaudito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LC5NAbZ), [ánomalo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2jMTAIo) e [infrecuente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LZ9zw9I), pero se alejan más de la intención original.

Answer (score 3):

¿Qué tal *[capricho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7LgFNrQ)*?

> 1. m. Determinación que se toma arbitrariamente, inspirada por un antojo, por humor o por deleite en lo extravagante y original.

Así, tus ejemplos quedarían así:

> 1) Caprichosamente, se levantó aquel día a las nueve de la mañana.
>
> 2) Decidió por puro capricho que no quería café.

Tal vez no sea exactamente lo que buscas, pero es lo más cercano que se me ocurre.

¡Feliz año nuevo!

Comment: Es algo, gracias. Me queda cada vez más claro que no debe de haber una palabra que se ajuste con precisión a esta expresión.